# message confirmation windows phone 8

Tags: sms, messagebox

I have a question regarding Windows Phone 8 app development. I've made an app that is running in the background on Windows Phone 8. Is it possible to make a message box appear, like a confirmation (Are you sure you want to send this message? OK, Cancel) when the user is sending an SMS, MMS or making a call for example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently no API's to see if a user is sending a text message or if he's calling. Only trusted partners are able to do this. You can vote for this feature here: http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/1905841-please-allow-readonly-access-to-call-history-and